# Create a Post from External Website for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

All,
I'm trying to have someone fill out some information on my website and then create a post in wordpress for this. I didn't want to have them use the Wordpress admin panel since it could be confusing.

Within Wordpress I've updated my functions.php to create some postmeta data. I was using add_post_meta/update_post_meta etc. but now I want to create the actual post with some of the postmeta data.

Does Wordpress offer the same types of things to create a post from my website instead of in the admin panel or do I have to insert this directly into the database and create my postmeta data the same way?

I tried to use your example at the GitHub and created the following page:

```
require('xmlrpc.inc');
require('wp-content/themes/parallelus-mingle/new-post.php');

$globalerr = null;

$xmlrpcurl = 'http://localhost/vendor_wordpress/xmlrpc.php';

$username = 'admin';
$password = 'password';
$title = 'This is a test';
$content = 'This is some content';

$post = wordpress_new_post($xmlrpcurl, $username, $password, $blogid = 0, $slug = "", $wp_password="", $author_id = "0", $title, $content, $excerpt, $text_more, $keywords, $allowcomments = "0", $allowpings = "0", $pingurls, $categories, $date_created = '', $customfields = '', $publish = "1", $proxyipports = "");
if($post == false){
    echo $globalerr."\n";
    die();
}
else {
    print_r($post);   
}
```

I had to change the require from the xmlrpc.inc to xmlrpc.php but when I do this I get the following error:

XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wordpress supports](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) [XML-RPC](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/default.html). Use it with php.

See the [Wordpress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp).

PHP supports [XML-RPC](http://bd.php.net/xmlrpc)

Also Some fellow already written a PHP library for this.

- [Wordpress-XML-RPC-Library](https://github.com/picklingjar/Wordpress-XML-RPC-Library). [Readme](https://github.com/picklingjar/Wordpress-XML-RPC-Library#readme)
- [The Incutio XML-RPC Library for PHP](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/). [Tutorial](http://djzone.im/2011/04/simple-xml-rpc-client-to-wordpress-made-easy/)

#### Update 1

Your first 2 `require` call is wrong.

1. Download [`PHPXMLRPC`](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/) and put the `xmlrpc.php` in the current directory then include it. **Not** the `xmlrpc.php` from wordpress directory.
2. Download [Wordpress-XML-RPC-Library](https://github.com/picklingjar/Wordpress-XML-RPC-Library) library and `include` it.

You can also try [The Incutio XML-RPC Library for PHP](http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/).

Comment: This seems pretty complex. I'm just trying to create the form in Wordpress and post it to my database. I'll be online the whole time.

Comment: Ok, great. I'd very much appreciate that!

Comment: Thanks, if I have a form and I want to post it to that code on the Github, what would that look like? Sorry to keep asking questions just new to this XML-RPC.

Comment: Did you even look at the github page? It has [README](https://github.com/picklingjar/Wordpress-XML-RPC-Library#readme)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my question with my most recent code. I copied the new-post.php and then put in some content for the function. Do I need to pass all the arguments to the function? Why would it say that it only accepts post requests?

Comment: xml RPC accepts POST request by born. In fact the XML input is passed along with body part of the request

Comment: So if I basically copy the README file and update it to use the new-post.php instead of get-pages.php. I also updated the function like in my question. I'm not sure what is wrong. I copied the example in the README and used the get-pages.php to the same directory that I copied the new-post.php but even the README code gives me the same error.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice. It now interacts with Wordpress! However, I did get one error. The error is: Fatal error: Call to a member function serialize() on a non-object in D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\vendor_wordpress\xmlrpc.inc on line 3006